# Why doesn't my NestedScrollView position itself below my ConstraintView, although I use constraints?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

Can anyone help me?

I would like to place a NestedScrollView below a ConstraintLayout. Both of these layouts are in the same hierarchy level, within an outer ConstraintLayout.

**The hierarchy is structured like this:**

ConstraintLayout(1) contains ConstraintLayout(1.1) & NestedScrollView.

NestedScrollView contains ConstraintLayout(1.2).

ConstraintLayout(1.2) contains ConstraintLayout(1.2.1) & ConstraintLayout(1.2.2).

**My goal would be to place the NestedScrollView (with everything, which is inside) below ConstraintLayout(1.1).**

I have tried to align it using constraints. However, it does not work as desired, and it is not clear to me why the NestedScrollView is not aligned below the inner ConstraintLayout.

---

**Related code of the layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!-- +++++ OPENING BRACKET OF ConstraintLayout 1 +++++-->
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorwh">

    <!-- +++++ OPENING BRACKET OF ConstraintLayout 1.1 +++++-->
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/paymentDescriptor"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    <!-- +++++ CLOSING BRACKET OF ConstraintLayout 1.1 +++++-->

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/paymentRollover"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/paymentDescriptor"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <!-- +++++ OPENING BRACKET OF ConstraintLayout 1.2 +++++-->
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/availablePayments"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

            <!-- +++++ OPENING BRACKET OF ConstraintLayout 1.2.1 +++++-->
            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/buy_all"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/paymentMenuHeight"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/paymentMarginLeft"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/paymentMarginLeft"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/paymentMarginRight"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/paymentMarginRight"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/paymentMarginTop">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/flag_all"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/paymentFLAG_width"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/paymentFLAG_height"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/paymentTV_marginsVertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/paymentTV_marginLeft"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/paymentTV_marginLeft"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/paymentTV_marginsVertical">
                </ImageView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/language_all"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/paymentTV_width"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/paymentTV_height"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/flag_all"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/paymentTV_marginLeft"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/paymentTV_marginLeft"
                    android:text="@string/language_all"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/paymentTV_textSize"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textStyle="bold">
                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/descriptionBlock_all"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/paymentDescription_width"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/paymentDescription_height"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/flag_all"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/paymentDescription_marginVertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/paymentTV_marginLeft"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/paymentTV_marginLeft"
                    android:text="@string/descriptionBlock_all"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/paymentDescription_textSize"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textStyle="italic">
                </TextView>

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
            <!-- +++++ CLOSING BRACKET OF ConstraintLayout 1.2.1 +++++-->

            <!-- +++++ OPENING BRACKET OF ConstraintLayout 1.2.2 +++++-->
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/buy_de"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/paymentMenuHeight"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/paymentMarginLeft"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/paymentMarginLeft"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/paymentMarginRight"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/paymentMarginRight"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/buy_all"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/paymentMarginTop">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/flag_de"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/paymentFLAG_width"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/paymentFLAG_height"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/paymentTV_marginsVertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/paymentTV_marginLeft"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/paymentTV_marginLeft"
                android:background="@drawable/flag_col_1">
            </ImageView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/language_de"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/paymentTV_width"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/paymentTV_height"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/flag_de"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/paymentTV_marginLeft"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/paymentTV_marginLeft"
                android:text="@string/language_de"
                android:textSize="@dimen/paymentTV_textSize"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textStyle="bold">
            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/descriptionBlock_de"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/paymentDescription_width"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/paymentDescription_height"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/flag_de"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/paymentDescription_marginVertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/paymentTV_marginLeft"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/paymentTV_marginLeft"
                android:text="@string/descriptionBlock_de"
                android:textSize="@dimen/paymentDescription_textSize"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textStyle="italic">
            </TextView>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
            <!-- +++++ CLOSING BRACKET OF ConstraintLayout 1.2.2 +++++-->

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        <!-- +++++ CLOSING BRACKET OF ConstraintLayout 1.2 +++++-->

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    <!-- +++++ CLOSING BRACKET OF ConstraintLayout 1 +++++-->
```

Comment: `match_parent` can lead to some undesirable results in _ConstraintLayout_. Change `match_parent` to `0dp` with the appropriate constraints. That may, or may not, fix the problems but is a good place to start.

Comment: I will test this more extensively, but for now it looks like it will work with this approach. (Changing the height of the NestedScrollView from "match_parent" to "0dp"). Thank you!